How to use object string property values as property names for types in TypeScript
How to map the property values (pp1, pp2) of an object to the property names of the object?
const obj = {
  prop1: "pp1",
  prop2: "pp2",
};

// look here!
type test<T> = {
  [Property in keyof T as `${T[Property] & string}`]: string;
};

// expect
const tt: test<typeof obj> = {};
tt.pp1 = "123";
tt.pp2 = "123";


The problem that your obj's property values are of type string. So with your mapping test type you get a generic string as keys also. You could add as const to the obj's definition to get more precise literal string values and thus the keys. Also to see which keys are inferred in the mapped type you could add extends infer A ? A : never. Also the resulting type has readonly props like the source obj so if you don't need it, revert it with -readonly:
Playground
const obj = {
  prop1: "pp1",
  prop2: "pp2",
} as const;

// look here!
type test<T> = {
  -readonly [Property in keyof T as `${T[Property] & string}`]: string;
} extends infer A ? A : never;

// expect
const tt: test<typeof obj> = {
    pp1: '123',
    pp2: '123',
};


